# I don't know how to work on this large Photoshop file (300 inch x 320 inch). Please help!

Tags: adobe-photoshop, page-layout

Please, I need help with this issue:
I am working on a large **Photoshop file that has 32 artboards** with varying dimensions. This is for a specific project that requires these dimensions. The whole project has dimensions of **300 inches in height by 320** **inches in width**, and each board takes a part of that large area. When I work on the file, my 2TB SSD disks fill up to the max. I have 32 Rams, and they also fill up to the max. My CPU and GPU are good, but I don't notice a lot of CPU and GPU consumption. I can't even work on the file because it takes a really long time to adjust a tiny thing on the project.  What seems to be the problem here? How can I fix it? Is it a PC problem like low specs? What is an alternative approach I could use to continue working? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Should create such a large file.. could have split it to 4 or 6 artboards per file rather than 1 file with 32 artboards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not assemble it in Photoshop but in Illustrator or InDesign.
2. When you import a raster image of a piece of your puzzle, it will remain as it is, regardless you stretch it or squash it. If that piece is a 3000x3000px image, it will remain 3000x3000px.
3. You can also work at scale, let's say 1/10 30x32 inches.
4. At the end when you have all the projects, you can export a flattened JPG or TIFF file, at 300PPI or more. The final print will have 30PPI which is good to be viewed at a distance.
5. If you know you need more final resolution, work at a bigger scale, for example, 1/5.
6. Using InDesign will keep the working file small, because it only links to the images, do not embed them. Illustrator can do it both ways.